# Problems inserting typedef in std::map

Tags: c++

I've got a weird problem with inserting some typedefs in a simple `std::map`.
I defined threee types:

```
typedef std::vector<uint8_t>                  Generation_block;
typedef std::vector<Generation_block>         Generation_blocks;
typedef std::map<uint32_t, Generation_blocks> Generations_map;
```

So far no errors occur. Out of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046265/stdmap-with-typedef-type-in-it) I had the idea to do it this way to reduce confusion when reading the code. Now when I want to insert some values in the map, thing get worse:

```
Generation_block = gen_block; //gets filled with some uint8_t data
Generation_blocks = gen_blocks; //gets filled with some Generation_block
Generations_map gen_map;

uint32_t generation_id; //gets set to several values identifiying the packet generation (for rlnc network coding purposes)
gen_map.insert(generation_id, gen_blocks); //error occurs
```

The last line produces the error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::map<unsigned int, std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char> > >::insert(uint32_t&, Generation_blocks&)’
                 gen_map.insert(gen_id, gen_blocks);
```

But I don't really understand what I'm doing wrong here. Does anybody have a suggestion? Is there a problem with own typedefs I just not realized out of [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046265/stdmap-with-typedef-type-in-it)?

**EDIT #1:**

So I've build a minimal example:

```
#include<vector>
#include<cstdint>
#include<map>
#include<random>

typedef std::vector<uint8_t>                 Generation_data_block;
typedef std::vector<Generation_data_block>   Generation_blocks;
typedef std::map<uint32_t, Generation_blocks> Generations_map;

int main(){
        Generations_map gen_map;

        for(int j=0; j < 10; j++){
            Generation_blocks gen_blocks;

            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                Generation_block gen_block;

                std::generate(gen_block.begin(), gen_block.end(), rand); //generating randm data

                gen_blocks-push_back(gen_block);
            }

            uint32_t generation_id = j;

            gen_map.insert(generation_id, gen_blocks);
        }        
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can cut/paste this into our own system.  You are so close to having one all it needs is a complete program (including main) and a single block of code.

Comment: OK, I'll build one! Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Did you mean `gen_map.emplace(generation_id, gen_blocks);`? Considering `move`ing your `gen_blocks` into the map.

Comment: Hi, thanks four your comment! `std::map::emplace` could be useful with large objects. I'll definetly consider using that. But it doesn't refer to my problem since `emplace` also needs a `std::make_pair` to put data into the map. Edgar gave me the right hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gen_map.insert(generation_id, gen_blocks);
```

You cannot insert elements into the [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) in this fashion.

You need to change your code to:

```
gen_map.insert(std::make_pair(generation_id, gen_blocks));
```

or, simply:

```
gen_map.insert({generation_id, gen_blocks});
```

to be compliant with `std::map` [insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) method overloads.

[**DEMO**](https://godbolt.org/g/f4UiXo)

---

In addition to that, consider changing *typedefs* to *type aliases*:

```
using Generation_data_block = std::vector<uint8_t>;
// ...
```

as it is the preferable way to do the things since *C++ 11*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try that! Sounds good to me! ... So I tested this and it worked like a charm! I should repeat the basics in programming and read documentations carefully! Thank you so much! What is the advantage of type aliases?